# Less::Error expected expected ')' got '''

Tags: ruby, less, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline, less-rails

Recently I upgraded less-rails gem to 3.0.0. The error raised on stylesheet_link_tag, javascript_include_tag, image_tag and anywhere else that involving asset pipeline.

However when I prepend /assets/ e.g change from
`= stylesheet_link_tag "application"` to `= stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/application"` it works.

Error trace:

`` less (2.6.0) lib/less/parser.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in parse'
at Parser.parser.parse (less (2.6.0) lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:511:24)
less (2.6.0) lib/less/parser.rb:64:in `block in parse'
less (2.6.0) lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:90:in `block in do_lock'
less (2.6.0) lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:88:in `Locker'
less (2.6.0) lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:88:in `do_lock'
less (2.6.0) lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:60:in `lock'
less (2.6.0) lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:30:in `exec'
less (2.6.0) lib/less/java_script.rb:26:in `exec'
less (2.6.0) lib/less/parser.rb:63:in `parse'
less-rails (3.0.0) lib/less/rails/template_handlers.rb:18:in `evaluate'
tilt (2.0.8) lib/tilt/template.rb:109:in `render'
grease (0.3.1) lib/grease/adapter.rb:12:in `call'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:200:in `dfs'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `map'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `precompiled_assets'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:35:in `asset_precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:251:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:359:in `precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:363:in `raise_unless_precompiled_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:337:in `digest_path'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:325:in `asset_path'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:102:in `block in resolve_asset_path'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `block in resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `detect'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:101:in `resolve_asset_path'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:79:in `compute_asset_path'
actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:144:in `asset_path'
actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:254:in `javascript_path'
actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:61:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:59:in `map'
actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:59:in `javascript_include_tag'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:156:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:154:in `map'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:154:in `javascript_include_tag'
app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:185:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__1636334633396439568_70098641364520' ``

I tried removing one by one css and js file but it seems the issue are not with the files. Any idea?

Here is the output when I run `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` (file paths are ommited) :

`["/path/to/rails-project/app/assets/fonts", "/path/to/rails-project/app/assets/images", "/path/to/rails-project/app/assets/javascripts", "/path/to/rails-project/app/assets/stylesheets", "/path/to/rails-project/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/path/to/rails-project/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails-assets-jcrop-0.9.12/app/assets/images", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails-assets-jcrop-0.9.12/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails-assets-jcrop-0.9.12/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails-assets-jcrop-0.9.12/app/assets/templates", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails-assets-Sortable-1.4.2/app/assets/images", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails-assets-Sortable-1.4.2/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails-assets-Sortable-1.4.2/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails-assets-Sortable-1.4.2/app/assets/templates", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails-assets-react-bootstrap-0.28.1/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails-assets-react-0.14.3/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails-assets-classnames-2.2.0/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0/app/assets/images", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/images", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/bourbon-4.3.4/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/s3_file_field-1.3.0/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/s3_direct_upload-0.1.7/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/s3_direct_upload-0.1.7/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.1/vendor/assets/images", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.1/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/browser-timezone-rails-1.0.1/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/jstz-rails3-plus-1.0.5/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/js_cookie_rails-2.1.4/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/browser-timezone-rails-1.0.1/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails-4.17.37/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails-4.17.37/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/momentjs-rails-2.11.0/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/bootstrap-datepicker-rails-1.3.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/bootstrap-datepicker-rails-1.3.0.2/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/bundler/gems/surveyor-9563ce853417/lib/assets/fonts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/bundler/gems/surveyor-9563ce853417/lib/assets/images", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/bundler/gems/surveyor-9563ce853417/lib/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/bundler/gems/surveyor-9563ce853417/lib/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/turboboost-0.1.1/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/jquery-turbolinks-2.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/formtastic-3.1.5/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-1.0.14/lib/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/cocoon-1.2.6/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/jqcloud-rails-1.0.0/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/jqcloud-rails-1.0.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/pickadate-rails-1.5.0/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/pickadate-rails-1.5.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/bootstrap-slider-rails-9.8.0/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/bootstrap-slider-rails-9.8.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.2/app/assets/fonts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.2/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.2/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.2/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.7.0.2/app/assets/fonts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.7.0.2/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.1/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/actioncable-5.0.2/lib/assets/compiled", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/turbolinks-source-5.0.3/lib/assets/javascripts", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/react-rails-2.2.1/lib/assets/react-source/development-with-addons", "/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@gemset-name/gems/react-rails-2.2.1/lib/assets/javascripts/"]`

Comment: can you please run `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` in `rails console` and append the output in this question along with directory structure of relevant assets?

Comment: Hi Wasif I've added `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` output